# How do I get the text from an element that has two attributes?

Tags: xpath

I have a code such as:

```
<out:a>
<out:Name Type="First" TypeCode="Best">JAE</out:Name>
</out:a>
```

When I gave the xpath expression as 
    //*[name()='out:Name'], 
I got the result as

```
<out:Name Type="First" TypeCode="Best" xmlns:out3="abc" xmlns:out2="def" xmlns:out1="ghi" xmlns:out="jkl">JAE</out:Name>
```

I would like to get the value **JAE** using **xpath expression**. Could someone help me in that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text()` on the end:

```
//*[name()='out:Name']/text()
```

Or

```
//out:Name/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the tool you use.

With java / Xpath and **evaluate**, **your xpath expression works well**:

```
expression=" //*[name()='out:Name']";
String value = xPath.evaluate(expression, document);
System.out.println("EVALUATE:"+value); // => EVALUATE:JAE
```